Simplification of $\Gamma(a+ib) \cdot \Gamma(a-ib)$ and alternative forms
I've been exploring the gamma function recently and have gotten into exploring what the function like $$\Gamma((a+ib)x)\Gamma((a-ib)x)$$ might look like for x being a real variable.
Im looking around for simplifications of the gamma function multiplied at complex conjugate values but all I can find is that $$\lvert \Gamma(a+ib) \rvert^2 = \Gamma(a+ib) \cdot \Gamma(a-ib)$$ However I am looking for a way to alternatively express this so that I can analyze some of the properties of this product and get a grasp on it. I know the reflection formula for the gamma function exists as $\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ and that there are other results such as $\lvert \Gamma(bi) \rvert^2= \frac{\pi}{b\sinh(\pi b)}$ and $\lvert\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+bi)\rvert^2=\frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi b)}$ as seen on a site like wikipedia but I am wondering if one can come up with more general expressions similar to that for other potential conjugate evaluations of the gamma function multiplied by each other. Any help and clarity on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.8.E3 is probably the simplest you can get.
